# How can I mirror one Mac's screen to another?

Tags: mac, airplay

Here's the situation: I have a MacBook Air that I'd like to mirror the display (and audio) of to a Mac Mini, via WiFi.

It is completely possible to mirror the MacBook Air to an Apple TV (using "AirPlay Mirroring"), but I'd like to know if it's possible to do the same thing between two Macs, even if it means using third-party software.

More detail: the Mac Mini is connected to a screen only, there's no mouse & keyboard attached, so a solution that involves manually starting some software on it (e.g. Remote Desktop) is no good; I'd like something that just sits quietly and takes over the screen when it receives something from the MacBook.

Comment: so the screen sharing does not work then?

Comment: @Buscar웃 no if you want audio too

Comment: @Paolo you are right, but I commented before Jack changed his question :), see his Edit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can install the program "AirServer" on the Mac Mini to be able to AirPlay the display directly to it:

```
http://www.airserver.com/Download
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Airdisplay by Avatron this way you can use your 2nd's Mac Screen just as a normal 2nd Screen attached to you first Mac.

Then you just need to set the mirrored option in System Preferences.

And as a Plus there is also an App for iPad so if you like to take your screen with you just do the same thing with you iPad.

An other solution is to use VNC which is built in on OS X and free (read more about it on http://www.davidtheexpert.com/post.php?id=5) You just need to enable the VNC Server (you do this in the System Preferences under -> Network screen shot follows when im @home on my mac) on the one Mac you like to mirror and on the other start the VNC Client (called ScreenSharing) and connect to your other Mac.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a cleaner solution for someone who's needing to use a recent iMac as an external monitor for a recent Macbook. https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT204592

Comment: There is no mention of an iMac in the question. How is this relevant?

Comment: Apologies if this is not helpful, the question title was generic "macs" so thought this would be useful.